# Can't remove sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp0s20u3.device from boot

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, netctl

I've recently installed Arch and had some issues with Wired/Wireless, eventually got this fixed, but have a rogue device trying to load on boot:

`A start job is running for sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp0s20u3.device`, counts up thru 90 secs, then fails.

This was created when I plugged in a WiFi dongle to get connectivity whilst installing/configuring, it is no longer in use.  I've tried:

```
systemctl disable sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp0s20u3.device
Failed to disable unit: Unit file sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp0s20u3.device does not exist.

netctl disable sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp0s20u3
No regular unit file found for profile 'sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp0s20u3'
```

.

`systemctl reset-failed` results in no output, and changes nothing.  If I list similar units:

```
systemctl list-units --all | grep subsystem
sys-subsystem-net-devices-eno1.device      loaded    active   plugged   Ethernet Connection I217-V                                                 
sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp0s20u3.device loaded    inactive dead      sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp0s20u3.device
```

How can I get rid of this from attempting to load

Answer (score 2):

This problem appeared in my case, when I set up the `netctl-auto@*interface*.service` in a wrong way.
Try to remove the faulty sevice manually by removing the regarding file in
`/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`.